# Is there any way to point an A record of a web page to another website when that other website is on shared hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting, a-record

I am creating a web application that at this point I am using shared hosting to host. Is there any way for me to give my users the option to point the a record of their domain to my website and I display a certain page when that website is visited?

Sorry this is kind of convoluted. I am relatively new to the server side of web applications so I don't know all the specific words for things (or how to do most of them ;).

Comment: It probably is just a bad choice of words but DNS A records point to domains and hosts, not web pages.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers very true... just changed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking A records, and if I understand you correctly, I believe what you are looking for is IP-based virtual hosting. And yes, you can do this. I only have experience with Apache, but this should show you how to set it up:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/

You have to make sure that your server / OS is configured with an active network interface for the IP address in the A record, and you need to tell your web server to listen for incoming requests on this IP as well. If you do not have access to the OS or web server configs, you will have to see if this is something your hosting provider allows, and ask them to set it up for you.

Good luck.

Comment: He said he's on shared hosting, which all but guarantees he doesn't have access to the Apache config.

Comment: @ceejayoz Two things. 1: Please re-read my last paragraph. Specifically, "... If you do not have access to the OS or web server configs, you will have to see  ...". This acknowledges he may not have this option. 2. Note his excerpt "... at this point..." which implies he may, at some time in the future, have his own setup. He'll want to know this info.